# Source code highlighting with pygments and html output

Tags: python, html, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I am using Pygments as a source highlighter for documenting a C++ project. Both Python 2.7.x and Pygments are their latest versions. I am having trouble getting a highlighted html output for my source code when I run pygments using command line:

```
pygmentize  -f html -o a.html test1.cpp
```

The result is a colorless html output. Curiously, running the same command with Rich Text File format results in a colored rtf file:

```
pygmentize  -f rtf -o a.rtf test1.cpp
```

I tried a simpler C code and the html output was highlighted correctly. Any ideas why this is happening? The sample code I am having trouble with is [here](http://dpaste.com/1401076/plain/)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same thing with C++. Since you know what language to highlight ahead of time, try this:

```
pygmentize -N test1.CPP
```

This will tell you which lexer pygmentize will use. It should be CppLexer but if not then tell pygmentize to use the CppLexer lexer:

```
pygmentize -f html -o a.html -l CppLexer test1.cpp
```

I know this was asked awhile ago and not surprising the sample code you posted is now gone therefore I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

pygmentize does not output any css in that html file, it only adds classes to html elements. For example:

```
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Graphics/RenderTexture.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/System/Vector2.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Window/ContextSettings.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Window/Event.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;SFML/Window/WindowStyle.hpp&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
<span class="cp">#include</span><span class="w"> </span><span class="cpf">&lt;box2d/b2_math.h&gt;</span><span class="cp"></span>
```

As you can see, you can write a simple css that looks like this:

```
.cp {
    color: green;
}
```

And all preprocessor calls will be green. Repeat this for all the class values you will see (maybe use italics for comments etc.)